# Caixa de busca em Java

Tags: java, swing

Estou criando um sistema em Java, utilizando o NetBeans. Gostaria de criar uma caixa de busca que mostrasse os resultados em uma lista (de tamanho variável) embaixo da caixa à medida que o usuário vai digitando o texto a ser pesquisado. Seria algo semelhante à caixa de busca do Google, que mostra sugestões enquanto o usuário está digitando.

O sistema também deverá permitir que o usuário selecione resultados da busca, sem que os outros resultados sejam ocultados. Gostaria que a lista de resultados pudesse ficar sobre outros componentes da interface.

Gostaria também que fosse possível pesquisar a partir de determinadas células em uma tabela e que os resultados fossem exibidos embaixo da célula usada para pesquisa.

Não conheço nenhum componente da classe `Swing` ou funcionalidade do NetBeans que possa fazer isso. Alguém tem alguma ideia?

Comment: Tente usar o `JComboBox`.

Comment: Acho que não é bem o que eu queria. Gostaria que fossem exibidos apenas os resultados e não todas as opções, como nesse componente. Além disso, parece que esse componente realiza a busca somente pelo começo da frase e eu gostaria que também fossem exibidos resultados que tivessem a expressão pesquisada no meio da frase. Minha ideia é que a busca fosse feita no banco de dados MySQL e que os resultados fossem retornados à medida que o usuário vai digitando.

Comment: Para realizar uma busca conforme o usuário for digitando, você pode usar o JComboBox como o amigo @Victor Stafusa disse, adicionar um evento de change no componente e realizar a buscar no banco com os que já tem atualizado seu grid a cada evento change que fosse realizado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que encontrei mais próximo disso foi o uso da lib [SwingX](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.swinglabs/swingx/1.6.1) para decorar um `JComboBox`.

```
AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(combobox);
```

Exemplo:

```
 public class ExemploCombo {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("");
    AutoCompleteDecorator decorator;
    JComboBox combobox;

    public ExemploCombo() {
        combobox = new JComboBox(new Object[]{"","Diego", "Bruno",
        "Bianca", "Fernando", "Davi"});
        AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(combobox);
        frame.setSize(400,400);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        frame.add(combobox);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExemploCombo d = new ExemploCombo();
    }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26550559/how-to-create-a-search-bar-similar-to-google-search-style-in-java-gui